# CPU is close to 100% in R while loop

Tags: r

I am trying to create a query on the fly with IN clause in oracle.
The problem is that oracle doesnt allow more than 1000 items within IN clause so I am using multiple IN clauses separated by OR.

```
# expectedOutput has the values in column 1 which I have interest in 

uniqueCol <- df[4, 2]

teststring <- ""
teststring <- paste(uniqueCol, " in (", sep = "")
i <- 1
while (i < nrow(expectedOutput)) {
   if (i %% 1000 == 0) {
      teststring <- substr(teststring, 1, nchar(teststring) - 1)
       teststring<- paste(teststring, ") OR ", uniqueCol, " in (", sep="")
   }
   teststring <- paste(teststring, "'", expectedOutput[i, 1], "',", sep="")
   print(i)
   i <- i + 1
}
```

This is taking around 60 Minutes to run on 8 GB , dual core machine.

How can i speed this up?

Comment: What is `uniqueCol`? Could you paste a first few rows of `expectedOutput` as a sample? (Preferably in code.) What is `nrow(expectedOutput)` (approximately at least)?

Comment: First step: remove `print(i)` from your code. Printing is sloooow. If the code is still too slow then, rewrite it without the loop.

Comment: I can remove print(i) it was just to check the progress, nrow(expectedOutput) is around 200k with values such as 'A-0001', 'A-0002....' , I should have this in a variable before comparing in while else it would be calculated every-time. Main question was around the use of loop. Can this be avoided or is there a faster way to iterate?

Comment: Is it not more efficient to create a temporary table in Oracle, then join the tables instead of using "IN" with "OR"?

Comment: @zx8754 yeah I know ,but dont have rights for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem caused mainlyby the fact that you concatenating the constantly growing string `teststring` with a new substring in each round. The result is exponentially growing runtime. This effect was worsened by using the whole data.frame in each steps, and by the `print(i)` line too. Fixing these will drastically speed up the code.

On my machine with 10000 rows in `expectedOutput` it takes 6-7 seconds, for 50000 rows it takes 2 minutes, for 100000 rows it takes 6-7 minutes and for 200000 rows it takes 24-25 minutes to run the initial code below. This could be dropped to 3-4 seconds for 50000 rows, and just 11-12 seconds for 200000 rows with the steps following after it.

First I mocked up some data for the test:

```
expectedOutput <- cbind(
  db_col_name = c(paste0("A-", c(paste0("0", c(paste0("0", c(paste0("0", 0:9), 10:99)),
                                               100:999)), 1000:9999)),
                  paste0("B-", c(paste0("0", c(paste0("0", c(paste0("0", 0:9), 10:99)),
                                               100:999)), 1000:9999)),
                  paste0("C-", c(paste0("0", c(paste0("0", c(paste0("0", 0:9), 10:99)),
                                               100:999)), 1000:9999)),
                  paste0("D-", c(paste0("0", c(paste0("0", c(paste0("0", 0:9), 10:99)),
                                               100:999)), 1000:9999)),
                  paste0("E-", c(paste0("0", c(paste0("0", c(paste0("0", 0:9), 10:99)),
                                               100:999)), 1000:9999))),
  data.frame(replicate(100, sample(0:1000, 50000, rep=TRUE))))
uniqueCol <- "COLUMN_NAME"
```

The code was running for the initial test:

```
teststring <- paste(uniqueCol," in (", sep = "")
i <- 1
while(i < nrow(expectedOutput)){
  if(i %% 1000 == 0){
    teststring <- substr(teststring, 1, nchar(teststring) - 1)
    teststring <- paste(teststring, ") OR ", uniqueCol, " in (", sep="")
  }
  teststring <- paste(teststring, "'", expectedOutput[i, 1], "',", sep="")
  print(i)
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Removing the `print(i)` reduced the running time around 1.6 minutes for 50000 rows.

Concatenating substrings in 1000 steps, then storing them in a vector, then concatenating the vector at the end reduced running time dramatically: around 5-6 seconds for 50000 rows:

```
teststring <- character(0)
teststr_tmp <- paste(uniqueCol," in (", sep = "")
i <- 1
while(i < nrow(expectedOutput)){
  if(i %% 1000 == 0){
    teststr_tmp <- substr(teststr_tmp, 1, nchar(teststr_tmp) - 1)
    teststr_tmp <- paste(teststr_tmp, ") OR ", uniqueCol, " in (", sep="")
    teststring <- c(teststring, teststr_tmp)
    teststr_tmp <- paste(uniqueCol," in (", sep = "")
  }
  teststr_tmp <- paste(teststr_tmp, "'", expectedOutput[i, 1], "',", sep="")
  i <- i + 1
}
teststring <- paste(teststring, collapse)
```

Finally, putting the first column of `expectedOutput` to a separate vector further reduced the running time to 3-4 seconds for 50000 rows, and just 11-12 seconds for 200000 rows:

```
teststring <- character(0)
teststr_tmp <- paste(uniqueCol," in (", sep = "")
i <- 1
expectedOutputValues <- expectedOutput[[1]]
while(i < length(expectedOutputValues)){
  if(i %% 1000 == 0){
    teststr_tmp <- substr(teststr_tmp, 1, nchar(teststr_tmp) - 1)
    teststr_tmp <- paste(teststr_tmp, ") OR ", uniqueCol, " in (", sep="")
    teststring <- c(teststring, teststr_tmp)
    teststr_tmp <- paste(uniqueCol," in (", sep = "")
  }
  teststr_tmp <- paste(teststr_tmp, "'", expectedOutputValues[i], "',", sep="")
  i <- i + 1
}
teststring <- paste(teststring, collapse="")
```

Comment: You have to fix the end of teststring before passing to SQL, but I think it does not belongs here. Also this could be better written, but I want to stick more or less with your solution. Just some tips: If I would use loops, here `for` loop is more readable for me. Instead of loops I would go with `*apply` functions, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot oszkar, i ill give it a try, just a quick thing what if the total iterations are < 500. I will check that.